# How do I change my iChat name?

Tags: ichat

Now I am using iChat, have set my nickname to be Ben Potter, yet for some reason I always show up as "Jennifer Potter"...

do you know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Quit iChat if it is open.
2. Open Address Book.
3. Choose Card > Show My Card.
4. Click the Edit button.
5. Edit your first and last name.
6. Save changes by clicking the Edit button again or by selecting a different card.
7. Open iChat. Your revised name appears after you log in.